# Reading tabs count or info from IE running tasks vb.net

Tags: vb.net, system.diagnostics

Apologies for not formulating the question to its best. I hope the question is clear enough after going through the code below.

I am trying to get the TABS info running for an IE instance usung System.diagnostic class
It apparently is clear that VB.net returns only the active tab info

```
    Dim c_process As Process
    c_process = New Process
    Dim c_m_process() As Process

    c_m_process = Process.GetProcessesByName("iexplore")
    For Each all_prcsfound In c_m_process 
        TextBox1.Text += all_prcsfound.Id & "--" & all_prcsfound.ProcessName & "--" & all_prcsfound.HandleCount & "," & all_prcsfound.MainWindowTitle.ToString() & vbNewLine
    Next
```

Result---

12032--iexplore--620,
7456--iexplore--637,Ask a Question - Stack Overflow - Internet Explorer
15816--iexplore--671,
12660--iexplore--554,

What properties can get the
1)  IE.TABS.count info [ if exists ] 
2)  and how to access the tab(1).Titlename [ if exists ]  by one of the many available properties?

Thanks in advance
Rajiv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you will have to resort to Win32 API calls. I don't think this can be solved with pure .NET.

The process will get you the MainWindowHandle. From there you can use API function FindWindowEx to get ahold of the different child windows (tabs).